# How to check if a ImageView has a Bitmap with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to check if a ImageView has a bitmap on it and it's not working..

I tried

`Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) IdFront.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

but it retunrs `""`

and `imageViewOne.getDrawable() == null`

and finally :

```
private boolean hasImage(@NonNull ImageView view) {
 Drawable drawable = view.getDrawable();
 boolean hasImage = (drawable != null);

 if (hasImage && (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
     hasImage = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() != null;
 }

 return hasImage;
```

But the Bitmap returns `""` and not null.

[image]

Comment: What the IDE shows on mouse-over is basically going to be whatever `toString` returns, so it's not returning `""` per se.

Comment: So, basically, do you need to check if ImageView has a Drawable or you need to check if it has a BitmaoDrawable? why you need this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this：

```
        ImageView view = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) view.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

If you want to know `drawable` or `bitmap` variable value when debugging, you could see

```
drawable.toString() 
bitmap.toString()
```

like below fig:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

`boolean hasImage = (view.getDrawable() == null);`

Comment: Not working too, I'm putting the Image using `imageView.setImageBitmap`